# CRM Perfomance tool installation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am getting following error while importing data through the CRM Performance toolkit. Please help with solution:

System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CreateRegistryEntry(String categoryName, PerformanceCounterCategoryType categoryType, CounterCreationDataCollection creationData, Boolean& iniRegistered)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.RegisterCategory(String categoryName, PerformanceCounterCategoryType categoryType, String categoryHelp, CounterCreationDataCollection creationData)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(String categoryName, String categoryHelp, PerformanceCounterCategoryType categoryType, CounterCreationDataCollection counterData)
   at dbPopulator.DbPopulator.Main(String[] args)
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably because the account you are running the toolkit as doesn't have enough permissions. it looks like the toolkit is trying to write something to the event. Try running as a server admin to rule out any permissions issues.

Related info: [You receive the "Requested registry access is not allowed" error message when you try to create a custom event log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842795)